# Can you schedule a R managed notebook in Google Vertex ai?

Tags: r, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've built an Arima model using R in a managed notebook in Google Vertex Ai,the code runs perfectly it can read the data from google big query and it can also write. When I try to add a scheduler to it by using the execute button a scheduler is created , however, it never seems to execute the code in the notebook

I tried changing the gpu, where the notebooks is stored in the cloud storage, the environment